# How to produce bmatrix in pmatrix?

Tags: equations, matrices

I wish to produce the following:

[image]

So, far I only achieved the following:

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
v_a\\
v_y \\
\end{pmatrix}
\sim \mathcal{N} \begin{pmatrix}
\bar{v}_a, &  \sigma_a^2 & \sigma_{ay}\\
\bar{v}_y & \sigma_{ay} & \sigma_y^2 
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can simply use `\left(...\right)` and nest two matrices inside it:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
v_a \\
v_y
\end{pmatrix}
\sim \mathcal{N}
\left(
  \begin{matrix}
    \bar{v}_a \\
    \bar{v}_y
  \end{matrix}
  \mathrel{,}
  \begin{bmatrix}
    \sigma_a^2 & \sigma_{ay} \\
    \sigma_{ay} & \sigma_y^2
  \end{bmatrix}
\right)
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

You can nest matrices, just use a `matrix` environment for the first column of N:

[image: Sample output]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
  \begin{pmatrix}
    v_a\\
    v_y 
  \end{pmatrix}
  \sim \mathcal{N} \begin{pmatrix}
    \begin{matrix}
      \bar{v}_a\\ \bar{v}_y
    \end{matrix},
    &
    \begin{bmatrix}
      \sigma_a^2 & \sigma_{ay}\\
      \sigma_{ay} & \sigma_y^2
    \end{bmatrix}
  \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

However you may wish to add some negative space `\!` or more, e.g. `\mkern-9mu`, before the `bmatrix`

Comment: @AdnrewSwann your answer works as perfectly as the one by egreg

Answer (score 1):

The package `nicematrix` provides an environment `{pNiceArray}`, and with that environment, you can put delimiters in its preamble. That means that you can write `\begin{pNiceArray}{c[cc]}` and it will do the job (that syntax has been inspired by the package `blkarray`).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\begin{pmatrix}
v_a\\
v_y \\
\end{pmatrix}
\sim \mathcal{N} 
\begin{pNiceArray}{c[cc]}
\bar{v}_a &  \sigma_a^2 & \sigma_{ay}\\
\bar{v}_y & \sigma_{ay} & \sigma_y^2 
\end{pNiceArray}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

You need several compilations (because `nicematrix` uses PGF/Tikz nodes under the hood).

[image: Output of the above code]